# Gopalan Nairude Thadi

Tags: indian-cinema, adaptation

According to Wikipedia and [PRD, Govt. of Kerala website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303234157/http://www.prd.kerala.gov.in/stateawards3.htm), Indian actor [M. R. Gopakumar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._R._Gopakumar) won the Kerala State Film Award for the Second Best Actor in 1999 for his performance in the film ***Gopalan Nairude Thaadi*** (Malayalam:*ഗോപാലൻ നായരുടെ താടി*). I tried Googling many times, but couldn't find any info about this film. All I could find is that **there's a collection of short stories of the same title** by the renowned author [Uroob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uroob).

[image]

- Who's the director of this film?
- Why does the film go unnoticed?